# How this equation happens and what it describes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, rocket-science

I'm having some trouble with Momentum and Impulse,

In this equations,

Thrust = F = m * a = dp / dt = m * (dv / dt) + v * (dm / dt)

How is the,

**m * (dv / dt) + v * (dm / dt)**

Happens, and what it means?

[image]

Comment: I added the entire page i saw this equation @Farcher.

Comment: But I'm already in stuck with this equation and description, what it trying to mean? @Farcher

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule

Comment: Well done! Thanks @BowlOfRed I like it! Does order of rules important in here?

Comment: For future reference please note that although the equation has been differentiated correctly that differential form should not be used to derive the rocker equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m$ and $v$ are both functions of time, then
$$\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} (m(t)v(t)) = m\frac{dv}{dt} + v\frac{dm}{dt}, $$

by the product rule for differentiation.

Comment: It's good to see this. I did never see this, so what is this `d` key in these equations? Means, delta or etc?

Comment: @MuhammedÇağlarTUFAN It's a differential, which is similar in many ways to a delta.  It's a core part of calculus.  While you can learn a lot of mechanics and other introductory physics without calculus, many guides and courses will use calculus (and traditional calculus notation).

Comment: I understood @BowlOfRed, I will need calculus more therefore here. So I will learn too :) Thanks, have a good day you all!

Comment: That's where you note that the `correct' typesetting, $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}$ does help realise $\mathrm{d}$ is not a variable!

Answer (score 0):

Momentum is very important in physics, it is always conserved in a closed system. Closed here means that you can only lose momentum if stuff is actually leaving your system. It is conserved so when one object gains momentum, some other object has to gain the same amount of momentum but in the oppositive direction. If you consider a sytem of two parts you can write this conservation of momentum as follows:$$\Delta p_1=-\Delta p_2$$
This means when part 1 of the system changes its momentum by $\Delta p_1$ the other part has to change its momentum by $-\Delta p_2$ such that the total change in momentum is zero. If you divide both parts by $\Delta t$ and take the limit $\Delta t\rightarrow dt$ you get the following differential equation:
$$\frac{dp_1}{dt}=-\frac{dp_2}{dt}$$
This equation is another way to say conservation of momentum. Force is actually defined as $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ so this can be written as $F_1=-F_2$, which is a way to write Newton's third law.

Now to get to your equation; suppose you want to calculate the force that is acting on a moving object. Let's start with a car because the mass of the car doesn't change (much) while it accelerates. Momentum is defined as $p=mv$, so the force is given by
$$F=\frac{d}{dt}(mv)=m\frac{d}{dt}(v)$$
In the last line we used that the mass of the car is constant. So if we know the speed the car at any time we just have to take the derivative of the speed and multiply it by the mass to know how much force is acting on the car at any time. The same force is also applied to the ground but because the earth is so large (very large!) you don't notice that it's accelerating.

Now we can look at the rocket, one system is the rocket itself and the other system is the exhaust. This time the mass of the rocket changes (it gets lighter as it uses up fuel) so we have to use the product rule:
$$F=\frac{d}{dt}(mv)=m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}=m(t)a(t)+v(t)\frac{dm(t)}{dt}$$
The force on the rocket is calculated by this last formula. The mass, acceleration and velocity are now all time dependent. The exhaust, being the second system, has momentum opposite to the rocket so total momentum is conserved and the rocket can accelerate.

Comment: In you last equation what is $v(t)$? Note that if there is no external force $F$ on the rocket and the rocket is not moving, $v(t)=0$, then the rocket stays at rest as $a=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is very fit to my question. Thanks so much, I want to +1 your answer but im under 15 reputation, sorry. And another question, what is v(t) and why is?

Comment: @Farcher $v(t)$ is the velocity with of the exhaust with respect to the rocket, good that you point that out. Imagine a bigg mass $M$ with zero velocity. If you break off a small mass $\Delta m$ and give it a speed $v$, what momentum $\Delta p$ will it impart on the big mass? You can assume $M$ is so much larger than the small mass that the big mass stays stationary.

Comment: But the velocity of the exhaust relative to the rocket is constant, so what is the $v$ $\frac{dv}{dt}$?